# Automatically create variable names (merge strings)

Tags: macros, strings

i can't figure out how to solve my issue. A little bit Background info so you understand, why I would do such things:
I have some variables that contain numbers. Because this is not possible (as far as i know) i did name then like: VoltageI VoltageII etc.
I now want to process them in a for loop with the loopcounter. This works nice for figures i named figure1 etc. ->

```
includegraphics{path/figure\arabic{counter}}.
```

My Goal is to Substitute the Counter (in this case 1) with a I and so on. I already wrote a new command:

```
\newcommand{\Romannum}{%
\ifnum #1=1
#1I
\fi
}
```

For the Code in my text:

```
\Romannum{Profile}{1}
```

This prints me:

```
ProfileI
```

as intended. But I Need the Output not as a text but as a variable Name to Display the Content of the variable->

```
\ProfileI
```

Is this even possible or is there an easier way to get numbers in variable names?

Thank you!

Here an example (it doesnt compile due to the lack of the image but it makes my question more clear.)

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{forloop}
\newcommand{\Romannum}[2]{%
\ifnum #2=1
#1I
\fi
 \ifnum #2=2
#1II
\fi
} 

\newcommand{\ProfileI}{Some text is written here.}
\newcommand{\ProfileII}{Some text is written here.}

\newcounter{profilecounter}
\setcounter{profilecounter}{1}

\begin{document} 
\forloop{profilecounter}{1}{\value{profilecounter} < 3}{%
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{Profil\arabic{profilecounter}.png} %This works
\caption{Profile \arabic{profilecounter} -~\Romannum{Profile}{profilecounter}}%This doesnt work (it writes ProfileI. I'd need \ProfileI to acces the string in the variable.
 \end{figure}
 }

\end{document} }
```

Comment: What does define `\ProfileI` then?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the description you give, but in general, `\csname text\endcsname`, refers to a macro equivalent to `\text`.  Likewise, `\csname\Romannum{Profile}{1}\endcsname` could be used to refer to a macro `\ProfileI`.

Comment: `\newcommand{\Romannum}[1]{%
\ifnum\value{#1}=1
\csname #1I\endcsname
\fi
}` if `#1` will be the counter ?

Comment: Or easier: `\newcommand{\Romannum}[1]{%
  \csname #1\Roman{#1}\endcsname
}`?  -- Actually, I don't understand what you want to achieve here

Comment: For example, `\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\Romannum}[2]{#1\romannumeral#2}
\begin{document}
Define: \expandafter\def\csname\Romannum{Profile}{1}\endcsname{My own macro}

Employ:\csname\Romannum{Profile}{1}\endcsname
\end{document}`

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the fast replies! \ProfileI is defined automatically with some text, read out of a csv. I'll try the suggestions you gave me and if i fail i'll try to make it more clear.

Comment: @Jonas: It would be generally better to be clear right from the beginning ;-)

Comment: There's a trick to use arabic figures in macro names: `\@namedef`, but `\Profile1` won't work still

Comment: Okay. I tried to be clear in the first run but it didnt quite work ;-) So here we go again. I already defined Variables like ProfileI ProfileVI etc. and i want to process them in a loop so i will Need to Count up the variable Name and i dont know how to Count up stings. That's why i tried to transform the loop Counter into strings (depending on its value) and then i Need to go back from int to string to read the variable called ProfileI in the first run of the loop and so on.

Comment: Okay. I added some code to my Initial question. Thanks :-)

Comment: \forloop is not defined.

Comment: ... nor is `graphicx` included ;-)... and there is an additional `}` after `\end{document}` -- it does no harm there, but it looks weird ;-)

Comment: The *best* way to be clear is to add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what you are doing with the result that people are wasting their time, and yours, in posting solutions that solve something that is close to, but different from, your problem. Please post a MWE so that we can see what you are trying to do!

Answer (score 2):

You can use e.g. `expl3` to convert the current value of your counter to a Roman number:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forloop}
\newcommand{\ProfileI}{Some text for I is written here.}
\newcommand{\ProfileII}{Some text for II is written here.}

\newcounter{profilecounter}
\setcounter{profilecounter}{1}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn 
 %changed to expandable to get it in the listoffigures.
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\usecurrentProfile {}{ \use:c {Profile\int_to_Roman:n{ \value{profilecounter} }}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\listoffigures 
\forloop{profilecounter}{1}{\value{profilecounter} < 3}{%
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
%graphic
\caption{Profile \arabic{profilecounter} -~\usecurrentProfile}%
 \end{figure}
 }

\end{document}
```

[image]